# Edit java options with sed

Tags: sed, java-opts

```
 ...
 tomcat.javaoptions=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack\=true \
-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses\=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port\=12345 \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=${application.hostname}
 ...
```

I need add new line to the end of tomcat.javaoptions with sed.  I have to use regex, because I do not know how java options will look originally. i know only that it starts from `tomcat.javaoptions=` and can have multiple lines.  Any idea?

**EDITED:**
I need to add new line

```
 ...
 tomcat.javaoptions=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack\=true \
-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses\=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port\=12345 \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=${application.hostname} \
-agentpath:/opt/agent/agent.so,name=agent
 ...
```

I tried it just to add only "-agentpath" but no luck

```
sed -i "/^tomcat.javaoptions=(.*/n*)*/s/$/ \\\\\n  -agentpath/g" file
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the end of `tomcat.javaoptions` condition is, but I modify your script, so it works:

```
sed -r -i -e "/^tomcat.javaoptions=(.*\n*)*/s/$/ \n  -agentpath/g" File
```

Changes:

- Remember to add `-r` parameter to `sed`,
- replace your `/n` with `\n`.